# How to use shutil.copytree without copying parent file path?

Tags: python, shutil

I am very new to Python, and am working through some exercises in the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python book. I am learning how to organize files using Python. I am confused about what happens when I use `shutil.copytree()`. When I use it, it copies my source folder, and every parent folder in its file path to my destination, but I don't want the parent folders.

---

I have two directories:

Directory 1: `/Users/myname/f1/f2/f3/f4/f5`

Directory 2: `/Users/myname/fALPHA/fBETA/fCHARLIE/fDELTA`

---

I want to copy everything starting at `f3` to the `fDELTA` folder. I want the new directory to look like this:

`/Users/myname/fALPHA/fBETA/fCHARLIE/fDELTA/f3/f4/f5`

---

My current code is this:

```
shutil.copy('/Users/myname/f1/f2/f3','/Users/myname/fALPHA/fBETA/fCHARLIE/fDELTA')
```

However, what I end up getting is this:

`/Users/myname/fALPHA/fBETA/fCHARLIE/fDELTA/Users/myname/f1/f2/f3/f4/f5`

I don't want it copying all of these parent folders. I just want the tree that begins at the specified source.

I know this seems simple, but I just can't seem to find an solution.

Comment: What code are you using?
 `shutil.copytree("/Users/myname/f1/f2/f3", "/Users/myname/fALPHA/fBETA/fCHARLIE/fDELTA/f3")`
  Is this not giving you the desired result?

Comment: What @lc74 suggests should work. Note that the destination path in it ends with `/f3` unlike what you have in your current code. The documentation for `copytree()` specifies that the destination directory should not already exist, so you must specify one as part of the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Ic74, what you are missing is the name of the target directory under "fDELTA" folder,

```
from shutil import copytree
from_path = "/Users/myname/f1/f2/f3"
to_path = "/Users/myname/fALPHA/fBETA/fCHARLIE/fDELTA/f3"
copytree(from_path,to_path)
```